# Is it possible to create an AngularJS service without a module?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

In AngularJS there is a short form to create controllers, so you do not have to use a module for this. This short form is to simply define a function

```
function FooController ($scope) {
  // ...
}
```

and reference it from the HTML markup using `ng-controller`:

```
<div ng-controller="FooController">
  ...
</div>
```

Now, my question is, whether there is a similar "short form" to define services? In other words: Can you define (and use) a service without using a module?

*Please note that I know that it perfectly makes sense to structure your applications using modules, and not doing so could / should be regarded as bad practice. It's just that I am explaining AngularJS to someone who's completely new to it, and the question arose today. So it's just for curiosity and completeness.*

Comment: Quoted from the doc `To register a service, you must have a module that this service will be part of.`, so I guess the answer is no.

Comment: If you turn this into an answer and provide a link I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoted from the [doc of Creating Services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services)

> To register a service, you **must** have a module that this service will
>   be part of.

So I guess the answer is no.

Comment: incorrect.  see below.  you don't need a module, because you can use the 'ng' module.

Answer (score 5):

Since the `ng` module is always loaded, you could define your service on the `ng` module:

```js
angular.module('ng')
  .service('aService', function () {
    // you really shouldn't do this
  });
```

It works, but you shouldn't be messing with a module that you don't own.

If you're trying to explain to someone why using your own modules with `.controller` is good:

- Talk to them about testing. It's a lot easier to mock things if you're using modules
- If you need to have other modules as dependencies (like `angular-ui`)
- If you want to decorate another service (e.g. `$http`)
- If you need to register directives, filters, animations, etc.
- It's a lot nicer to have modular code :)

Answer (score 1):

It's an angular concept I don't understand at all, I always believed "separation" is good, so I dont get why we need to associate a service to a specified application.

Here what I am doing: you can declare your angularjs application as a global object:

```
window.markrApplication = angular.module('markrOptionsApp', ....)
```

And declare all your services like this:

```
markrApplication.service('data', ....
```

Of course you need to have all the dependencies set on all your angularjs application.