# Is it a good practice to bind factory with ng module?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

Below I am trying to bind factory with `ng` module, which helps me to direct injection.

```
var module = angular.module("ng");

module.factory("commonService", ["$http"]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't recommend [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the core `ng` module. Carelessly written or poorly documented monkey patches can lead to problems. See [Pitfalls of Monkey Patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch#Pitfalls).

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg but in my case I am not updating library for a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer here, one cannot create a factory without a module. We can bind factory with `ng` module but it is not considered as good practice.

Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317357/is-it-possible-to-create-an-angularjs-service-without-a-module)